# Object not found when called within a function with a formula

Tags: r

I'm trying to call the checkm function from within another function that accepts a formula as a parameter.  I'm getting an object not found error.  Here is the minimal implementation and error.

```
library(lrmest)
data(pcd)
form<-formula(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4)
checkm(form,data=pcd)


Wrap<-function(f){
  checkm(f,data=pcd)
}

Wrap(form)
```

The error is:

```
Error in model.frame(formula = f, data = pcd, NULL) : 
  object 'f' not found
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
```

My guess from reading around is this has to do with my not understanding environments or promises but given that I don't understand them, I'm probably wrong.

Any quick fixes?

Comment: Might be some sloppy coding by the lrmest authors, rather than a mistake on your part. Inside `checkm` they do `eval(cal)` rather than `eval(cal,parent.frame())`.

Answer (score 2):

One quick fix is to change the name of your formula argument.  It happens to conflict with the `eval(cal)` call within `checkm`.  I suspect @joran is right that this isn't your fault. This works:

```
library(lrmest)
data(pcd)
form<-Y~X1+X2+X3+X4
checkm(form,data=pcd)


Wrap<-function(formula){
  checkm(formula,data=pcd)
}

Wrap(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @joran pointed out, there is a bug/error in the function caused from not using the correct frame to evaluate the command. If you swap out `checkm` for `lm` you'll see it runs just fine. You can create your own function that changes just that one line of code with

```
checkm2<-checkm
body(checkm2)[[6]]<-quote(cal <- eval(cal, parent.frame()))
```

And then run

```
library(lrmest)
data(pcd)
form<-formula(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4)
checkm2(form,data=pcd)


Wrap<-function(f){
  checkm2(f,data=pcd)
}

Wrap(form)
```

and everything seems to run properly. So that just appears to be the fault of the people who wrote the code. You might consider contacting them to file a bug report.